# Console.Writeline basics

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I have a question about the following code:

```
class CurrentDate
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

Documentation says:

> Writes the text representation of the specified array of objects,
>   followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream
>   using the specified format information.

So my question is: How come `WriteLine` knows the text representation of `DateTime` object? I mean, if I create my own object from my own class, how would it know how to convert the value to text? And even more, how does it know what the value is? How can you define "value" of an object?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Note that Visual Studio Debugger's object inspector also uses a very similar mechanism (`MyClass.toString`) to figure out what to print as the value when the object is displayed as a single row.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` implicitly calls `ToString()`, so for your own object you have to implement/override `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How come WriteLine knows the text representation of DateTime object? I mean, if I create my own object from my own class, how would it know how to convert the value to text?

`Console.WriteLine` has a [set of overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) matching specific types (mainly primitives). If the compiler doesn't match an overload with the provided type, it matches with the overload taking `System.Object` (granted you provide a single parameter). If that happens, it checks to see if the type implements `IFormattable`, if it does, it invokes [`IFormattable.ToString(null, Formatter)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,aedbc5e502007cf7). If it doesn't, it invokes `ToString` on your object. `ToString` is defined in `System.Object` , which all objects inherit from. Every object that wants a custom representation overrides the default behavior, like `DateTime` does.

For example, lets say you have a `Foo` class with a `Bar` string property, and you want `Console.WriteLine` to print something meaningful when passing your `Foo` to it:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return Bar;
    }
}
```

And now we want to pass it `Console.WriteLine`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var foo = new Foo { Bar = "bar" };
      Console.WriteLine(foo);
}
```

Would yield "bar".

Answer (score 9):

Since there is no overload for `Console.WriteLine(DateTime)`,as in your case,the `Console.WriteLine(Object)` overload is called and [this overload calls](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,2059) the [`TextWriter.WriteLine(object)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zcc928k(v=vs.110).aspx) which is [implemented as](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,497):

```
IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
if (f != null)
    WriteLine(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
else
    WriteLine(value.ToString());
```

As you can see, this method checks if this object type implements [`IFormattable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx) or not. Since [`Datetime` implements this interface](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,57), your `f.ToString(null, FormatProvider)` will be called. From this method's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) the first parameter is:

> A null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) to use the **default format
>   defined for the type of the IFormattable implementation**.

And from the [`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) method's documentation:

> If format is null or an empty string (""), the standard format
>   specifier, [`"G"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralDateLongTime)., is used.

That means, the representation will be a combination of the [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) properties belonging to your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want a special format for your custom class, you can [override the `.ToString()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of your type to change its behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to what some persons think, `DateTime.ToString()` **won't** be called. In .NET, an object can have two ways to "stringize" itself: overriding the `string Object.ToString()` method and implementing the [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.iformattable.aspx) interface. `DateTime` does both.

Now... When you try doing

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

the void [`public static void WriteLine(Object value)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,17999987f8ff4399,references) overload is selected (you can see it if you Ctrl+Click on `WriteLine` in Visual Studio). This method simply calls the [`TextWriter.WriteLine(value)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,aedbc5e502007cf7) method, that does:

```
IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
if (f != null)
    WriteLine(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
else
    WriteLine(value.ToString());
```

All of this can be easily seen using ILSpy and looking for the `Console.WriteLine`.