# Date Time Format is not Formatting

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I need have this format :
aaaa-mm-jjThh:mm:sszzzzzz

And put it in a XML property "DateTime" type.

So, I did it :

```
var xmlObj= new xmlObj.tHeader();
xmlObj.prop = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"), "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(xmlObj.prop);
```

The Console.WriteLine instruction return : 03/05/2016 15:43:10

I don't understand why the property remove the format.

In the XSD, this property is waiting a datetime format.

Any ideas?

EDIT :

Ok, on the command result, I see a default format but If convert my XML object to File, the format is correct :

[image]

Very strange... but it's ok now. Many thanks to all of you

Comment: Do you need the speech marks or is yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ fine?

Comment: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ is fine

Comment: just curious, where does `xmlObj.tHeader` come from?

Comment: At the start, I have an XSD file. Then I use the command "xsd.exe" for create the "file.cs". And this is what I use

Comment: I've made an edit of my question. Command line is formatting the date, I think

Comment: There are plenty of questions complaining that `ToString` does not perfectly match one's expectations about how object should be represented... Have you ever tried `(new int[]{1,3}).ToString()`? - this is exactly the same as your question which is essentially - "I don't like how `DateTime` formatted by default. What should I do?"

Comment: [Console.WriteLine basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413683/console-writeline-basics) may be good duplicate for your question if you like it.

Comment: Sorry, do not know about it... Down vote for my question... wow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `DateTime.ParseExact`, which parses a string into a `DateTime` object. Just drop that part and assign the result of `ToString` directly to `xmlObj.prop`, or assign the `DateTime` object directly (if that's what it's looking for).

Edit:

To address your edit, your XML file is generated correctly. However, when you output the DateTime prop to the console, it uses the default string format for a date. You can format that with `ToString()` if you want to.

Comment: I can't : I have the error "Cannot convert a string to datetime"

Comment: If it's expecting a `DateTime`, skip the formatting entirely and assign the date value directly.

Comment: What you're doing in your code is making a round-trip conversion between a `DateTime` and a `String` - which has no actual effect.

Comment: Even I put this : xmlObj.prop = DateTime.UtcNow; //I have the same issue

Comment: I've made an edit of my question. Command line is formatting the date, I think

Answer (score 1):

You try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") + "Z");
```

Comment: This is ok but if I try to put it in 'prop', I have the error "Unable to convert a string to DateTime"

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong in parse, if you want `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssz` format then you have to convert it as string otherwise, it will represent standard datetime, try this

```
xmlObj.prop = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(xmlObj.prop.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssz"));
```

Comment: I've try your suggestion but no effect

Comment: if `xmlObj.prop` is datetime type then you have to cast it your desire type string otherwise it will always print the datetime as your system datetime format

Comment: I've made an edit of my question. Command line is formatting the date, I think

Comment: Suggestion to format local time as Utc is really questionable.